# How to check that the state has changed after a setTimeout in Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to check and see if the state was changed accordingly after a function has run in Jest and Enzyme. This function has a setTimeout within it that calls another function and depending on the result that function changes or does not change the state. I'm also struggling to get line coverage for the lines within the setTimeout function.

At the moment I have an onStart callback function that is passed as a prop to a component. In here it's able to check the current state and if showAuth is set to true, then the values for shown and customCSS are changed accordingly.

```
function onStart(){
  const that = this;
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(that.state.showAuth){
      this.setState({ shown: true, customCSS: `visible` })
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

This function is passed as a prop to the following component

```
  <CheckUser
    onSuccess={responseHandler}
    onStart={onStart}
  />
```

and the component will take the information and will render a pop up if showAuth in the state is true.

Now for my tests I have so far:

```
describe('onStart', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<UserInformation />);

/*the component I'm making a shallow copy of has the CheckUser component as a child*/

    it('runs setTimeout', () => {
      jest.useFakeTimers();
      wrapper.instance().onActivate()
      expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
})
```

Now, the tests pass but there is no coverage in the lines in setTimeout. I'm also not sure how exactly to go about checking that the state has changed, but at the moment I'm trying to focus on exactly how to cover everything that is within setTimeout in `onStart()`

I also want to note that everything is functioning as I want to in the app, my concerns are just for the test coverage.

Thank you!

Comment: As setState is asyncrhonous. You can pass a callback in setState this.setState({ shown: true, customCSS: `visible` }, function(){ //action here } )

Comment: Have you tried debugging the test case in chrome debugging tool? Just need to make sure that your test enters inside setTimeout() because if it doesn't enters then may be we need to change the rendering method instead of shallow rendering or we need to paas some threshold inside jest.useFakeTimers().

Comment: You can use [`jest.runAllTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks#run-all-timers) to execute the timeout callback.